# StorageFile.GetScaledImageAsThumbnailAsync does not support metadata rotated image

Tags: c#, windows, uwp, async-await, storagefile

1. Edit an image by Windows 10 editor. E.g. rotate the image:
   [image]
2. Try to open this image: `IRandomAccessStream thumb = await file.GetScaledImageAsThumbnailAsync(ThumbnailMode.SingleItem, 4096);`
3. The `GetScaledImageAsThumbnailAsync` method will never return with no error or exception.

---

I need this `IRandomAccessStream` in order to populate an internal map of `BitmapDecoder`:

```
_bitmapDict[index] = await BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(thumb);
```

Any ideia how to workaround `GetScaledImageAsThumbnailAsync`?

Comment: Could it be that the image just has no thumbnail associated with it and your getting `null` back?

Comment: @JSteward unfortunately not, the thumbnail is loaded normally... to load the thumbnail I'm using `file.GetScaledImageAsThumbnailAsync(ThumbnailMode.ListView, Convert.ToUInt32(textureWidth), ThumbnailOptions.ResizeThumbnail);`
and has no `null` as I mentioned its a async call (`await`) and it never returns, not even after 5 min...

Answer (score 0):

I could reproduce your issue, if you edit the image with image Editor then open it with `GetScaledImageAsThumbnailAsync` method, it could get `StorageItemThumbnail` however it will take a long time. The larger the picture, the more time it takes to use. Currently there is a workaround that edit your picture with Paint.

[image]

Comment: Once I'm working on an app I can't ask to the user open Paint and rotate properly don't you think?!

Comment: Yep, I know that, I will report this issue to related team.

Comment: @nico-zhu-msft thanks! please let me know if you have any feedback from them! :D

Comment: @nico-zhu-msft I've noticed too big images when you pass and too small width to scale this method never returns. If you reduce the image size and rotates via Windows editor, you can load the same image successfully...

Comment: Yep, the same behavior in my side.

Comment: Hi Marcelo, thanks for reporting this. We've been looking into it and it appears to be a known issue to the developers which is causing RuntimeBroker to spike a CPU core when performing this task for images with the rotated metadata like this. We're still investigating further.

Comment: I requested a fix for this. I can't guarantee when or if it will release, but please stay tuned to release notes for any updates. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/whats-new/